# Upgrading a solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013 with command-line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm building many Visual Studio projects (.sln solutions files) from command-line with:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

for /r %%X in (/*.sln) do (
msbuild %%X /p:configuration=release /p:platform=win32 /nologo /noconsolelogger /fileLogger /v:quiet /flp:logfile=build_errors.log;errorsonly;append
```

)

Unfortunately, they all have been created with MSVS2010. Thus I get errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(64,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".

As I have 20 or 30 .sln files, I don't want to open each one and Upgrade solution, etc. (which I even didn't find exactly as mentioned here!).

**Is there a command-line solution to upgrade all of them to MSVS2013 ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade solution and all of its project files through [devenv /upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/w15a82ay.aspx) command. (devenv.exe is in the VS installation path (..\Common7\IDE).

```
devenv SolutionFile | ProjectFile /upgrade
```

To build solution/project without upgrade, you can specify [Toolset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx) argument (/tv).

```
msbuild %%X /p:configuration=release /p:platform=win32 /tv:12.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a command line example, for future reference? Will `devenv /upgrade mysolution.sln` be enough? About the `/tv` argument, will it be with msbuild ? (an example would be great)

Comment: `devenv` isn't available in VS2013 Express, it is `WDExpress.exe`, but this doesn't include /upgrade, sadly... On the other hand, `/tv:12.0` didn't work for me, I don't know why.

Comment: @Basj There isn't other official tool/command to upgrade project/solution. The simple way is open solution through VS and upgrade, which is easily than change project file. What's the detail error when you build solution through MSBuild with /tv:12.0 argument? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only problem you can retarget the projects to use the `VS2013` toolset instead of the one in `VS2010`. You can write a simple script in a language of your choice (or even do it manually) that iterates over all of your project files and replaces the value of `PlatformToolset` property to the `<PlatformToolset>Visual Studio 2013 (v120)</PlatformToolset>`. Alternatively, you can download and install the VS2010 build tools from the SDK - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found `<PlatformToolset>` in the .sln nor in the .vcxproj files. Where should it be?

Comment: It should be in .vcxproj. Not sure about the specific value of it, probably will be `<PlatformToolset>v100</PlatformToolset>`. You might need to add it if it's not there. See this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7331f38-19dd-4efc-9525-12729d0b9521/how-to-set-the-default-platform-toolset?forum=vcgeneral